# Red items in HTML sudo lshw -html > ~/hardware.html

Tags: hardware

I am checking list of devices installed in my system

I used the following

```
 sudo lshw -html > ~/hardware.html
```

Many items come in red in that list, others come in a yellow color.

Does red mean there's something wrong with them?

Answer (score 2):

I am almost certain that the red colour indicates that the node in red is UNCLAIMED and yellow nodes are ENABLED (see below).

When I execute lshw -html, there is one item in red in the HTML report which, on the terminal listing, is status UNCLAIMED, eg    *-enclosure UNCLAIMED.

All other nodes on the computer are yellow in the HTML and do not have a status in the terminal listing, so I assume they are most likely to be ENABLED.

Not sure what colour the CLAIMED or DISABLED are, as there are no nodes on my computer with these statii on the terminal listing.

Extract from http://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter

**How to interpret lshw's output**

lshw displays nodes with attributes in a tree-like structure (that can be in indented plain text form, HTML, XML or graphically displayed in the GUI). Each node has its individual status: it be CLAIMED (potentially usable) or UNCLAIMED (no driver has been detected for this node), ENABLED (this device is supported and can be used) or DISABLED (this device is supported but has been disabled):

```
a node is marked as CLAIMED if a driver (usually a kernel module or a driver within the monolithic kernel) has been loaded for it
a node is marked as UNCLAIMED if no specific support for it has been loaded (or lshw has been unable to identify the driver)
a node is marked as ENABLED if a driver has been loaded for it and is fully functional
a node is marked as DISABLED if the node has been disabled by a configuration, some hardware failure, etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

In a hardware list report produced by `sudo lshw -html`, you can examine the html source to see what color represents what.  There is a css style block at the top which may include lines like the following:

```
.node-unclaimed {border: dotted thin #c3c3c3; padding: 1em; background: #fafafa; color: red; }
.node-disabled {border: solid thin #f55; padding: 1em; background: #fee; color: gray; }
```

These are your "red" styles, as follows:

"Unclaimed" (no driver present or detected for device) items are shown as red text on a light grey background in a box with a dotted thin border.

"Disabled" (driver present/detected but turned off in configuration or by failure) items are shown as dark grey text on a light red background with a solid thin border.

If in doubt, you can view source and search for the text `node-unclaimed`, `node-disabled`, etc.  to see what blocks they represent.  "Enabled" items seem to be simply marked with `class="node"` and show up on that yellow background.