# Problem with checking specifications of laptop

Tags: command-line, dell, laptop

When I type

```
sudo lshw -html > mySpecs.html
```

in my terminal, I get this in the HTML file:

[image]

Why is this red?
Does that mean I`m missing some drivers?If it does,how can I install them for this version?(I went to Dell site,but they offer only Windows supported drivers)

Does that mean something is broken in my laptop?

Comment: possible dupe of http://askubuntu.com/q/348151/595510